# Error while loading PowerShell ISE. Unable to run cmdlets

Tags: powershell

When I try to open PowerShell in my server it shows below error on loading:

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C
>   :\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml: The file was
>   skipped because of the followin g validation exception: File
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml cannot be
>   loade d because its operation is blocked by software restriction
>   policies, such as those created by using  Group Policy.. Errors
>   occurred while loading the format data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, , C:\Windows\System32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml: The file was
>   skipped because of the following val idation exception: File
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml
>   cannot  be loaded because its operation is blocked by software
>   restriction policies, such as those created b y using Group Policy..
>   Errors occurred while loading the format data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, , C:\Windows\System32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\FileSystem.format.ps1xml: The file was skipped
>   because of the following vali dation exception: File
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\FileSystem.format.ps1xml
>   cannot be  loaded because its operation is blocked by software
>   restriction policies, such as those created by  using Group Policy..
>   Errors occurred while loading the format data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, , C:\Windows\System32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml: The file was
>   skipped because of the following  validation exception: File
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml
>   c annot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software
>   restriction policies, such as those cre ated by using Group Policy..
>
> The 'set-variable' command was found in the module
>   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility', but the module could  not be
>   loaded.For more information, run 'Import-Module
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'.At line:0 char:0

Rest of the logged in users are able to run scripts but i'm unable to.

When I try to run any cmdlet for example

> `write-host 'test'`

I get an error like this

> writeErrorStream      : True Exception             :
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The
>   'write-host' command was found in the module
>   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility', but the module could 
>                           not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'. --->
>   System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: File 
>                           C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is 
>                           blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy. --->
>   System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: File 
>                           C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is 
>                           blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: File 
>                           C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is 
>                           blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
>                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                              at System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo
>   commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.GetScriptInfoForFile(String
>   fileName, String& scriptName, Boolean checkExecutionPolicy)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo
>   parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix,
>   SessionState 
>                           ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean&
>   found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo
>   parentModule, ModuleSpecification moduleSpecification, String 
>                           moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options,
>   ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean 
>                           loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String
>   moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, Hashtable data,
>   Hashtable 
>                           localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version version, Version requiredVersion,
>   Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, 
>                           ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo
>   scriptInfo, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, 
>                           Version version, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo
>   parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix,
>   SessionState 
>                           ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean&
>   found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName(ImportModuleOptions
>   importModuleOptions, String name)
>                              at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ProcessRecord()
>                              at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
>                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                              at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
>   input)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace
>   rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings 
>                           settings)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1
>   input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.InvokeT
>                              at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.AutoloadSpecifiedModule(String
>   moduleName, ExecutionContext context, SessionStateEntryVisibility 
>                           visibility, Exception& exception)
>                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                              at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.TryModuleAutoDiscovery(String
>   commandName, ExecutionContext context, String originalCommandName, 
>                           CommandOrigin commandOrigin, SearchResolutionOptions searchResolutionOptions, CommandTypes
>   commandTypes, Exception& lastError)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String
>   commandName, CommandTypes commandTypes, SearchResolutionOptions 
>                           searchResolutionOptions, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, ExecutionContext context)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String
>   commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String
>   command, Boolean dotSource)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor
>   pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, CommandBaseAst
>   commandBaseAst, 
>                           CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input,
>   Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements,
>   CommandBaseAst[] 
>                           pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)
>                              at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) TargetObject          : write-host CategoryInfo          :
>   ObjectNotFound: (write-host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule ErrorDetails
>   :  InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
>   ScriptStackTrace      : at , : line 1
>   PipelineIterationInfo : {}

please suggest me a solution to overcome this error.

Comment: `sfc /scannow`? that might help, as your system appears as good as dead

Comment: The first parts of the error reference software restriction policies, is AppLocker or a similar system in use on your network? as a test can you remove the system from the domain? or move it into the computers OU, run gpupdate, reboot, and try again?

Answer (score 0):

On the context, I can see that powershell is not able to load any of the default modules. Not only that but also it is failing to understand the ps1xml files.
This issue happens when a system is having some critical issue. 
I believe you should do a system restore or you should try a deep scan using sfc.

Hope this helps you